# Adding binary directory to cmake add_subdirectory fails

Tags: cmake

I am trying to move a library up one directory so it is at the same level as my project.
current directory structure (which works) is

```
/mnt/hgfs/project1
/mnt/hgfs/project1/src
/mnt/hgfs/project1/framework
```

What I want, is

```
/mnt/hgfs/project1
/mnt/hgfs/project1/src
/mnt/hgfs/framework
```

If I move the folder and change my cmake from

```
add_subdirectory(framework)  ->  add_subdirectory(../framework)
```

I get the error "when specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly specified"

so I researched and found that I should use a binary directory.

```
add_subdirectory(../framework, bin_framework)
```

I get the error `add_subdirectory given source "/mnt/hgfs/framework" which is not an existing directory`

I am on RHEL 6.3,  I have tried both cmake 2.8.4 and 3.3.1 and
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

I have tried not moving the directory at all and just adding the binary directory to my current working build,  this also fails stating source is not an existing directory.

```
add_subdirectory(framework, bin_framework)
```

I did also try full paths.

```
add_subdirectory(/mnt/hgfs/framework,{CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin_framework)
```

Thanks for any help,  this seems like it should be simple and I don't understand why it won't work

Comment: Arguments for CMake command are delimited with spaces, comma (',') is not needed: `add_subdirectory(../framework bin_framework)`.

Comment: Thanks!  that did fix the problem,  can't believe I missed that, I guess the error threw me off.    Feeling pretty silly right now..:)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you please add this as an answer, so that tamara can accept it and mark the question as answered?

Comment: @allo: On Stack Overflow we do not collect questions which are resolved via fixing the **typos** - such questions are not very useful for future visitors, because symptoms of the typos may be very different.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Anyway it is a open question. It should be either closed or answered or both. Users do not want to read the comments to find the answer and/or mistake in the question. And for *this* question, the answer "the syntax for cmake uses spaces instead of commas" is exactly right, even when the asker assumed that the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @allo: I have voted to close the question. But it needs other 4 persons for doing the same. BTW, if you have feelings that the question deserves the answer, you are free to write that answer. See [that question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) about policies in case of answer-in-the-comment. Among these policies, I prefer [that one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252027/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev A short accepted answer would be okay, even when the question is not that great. On the other hand, it may be unlikely that Tamara is still active. I came here from search and a closed question or a short answer would have been helpful to see quickly, that the question does not answer my question. I flagged for close as well now.